# "yourdomain/start is not the same thing as yourIP/start in Apache"

Tags: apache, installation, kaltura

Let's say you're trying to get a CMS up and going.

And say you're supposed to find a Start Page at "www.yourdomain.com/start"

But you don't have a domain name yet. You only have an IP address.

So you look in "yourIPaddress/start"

(Apache is visibly running at yourIPaddress)

And you don't find anything there, just a 404 page.

And the person who installed it for you tells you: "In Apache, yourdomain/start is not the same thing as yourIP/start. Please read up on Apache server configuration to figure this out. And that's all the help I can give."

My question is: what concepts (re: Apache configuration) should I read up on so that I can find the start page?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If the ip address is not exclusive for your website then it might be shared by other websites. In that case searching for details about virtual hosts you should be able to get more info.

what you can do to get things working is add to the hosts file on your machine

```
yourIPaddress www.yourdomain.com
```

and you should be able to access your website's start page from www.yourdomain.com/start.

Just remember to remove the entry from your hosts file after the www.yourdomain.com actually gets pointed to your yourIPaddres by your hosting provider.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion... problem is that this site is not hosted on my local machine, it's on a real server on the internet, with a public IP address (but without a domain name).

Comment: If the virtual host is setup and only the domain name pointing has not taken place then this should work even if the yourIPaddress is the public IP of the website.